# Not able to select values from drop down using select

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to select some value in the Device drop down but I am getting the error - element not intractable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

We are using knockout js for our application.
The drop down is not even opening.

```
I am using xpath - "//select[@class='deviceType']"
```

I am able to use webdriver wait for this that means there is no problem with the xpath but I am not able select the value in the dropdown

```
 Select device = new Select(deviceDrpDwn);
         device.selectByVisibleText(deviceOption);
```

This is the code I am using to select the drop down value. The dropdown is not opening.

```
HTML code:
<div class="span9 select-device">
                <!-- ko if: sdeviceConfigMap -->
                        <label data-bind="text: ovd.ui.admin.hart.device">Device (Manufacturer ID, Device Type, User Extension, Characterization)</label>
                        <select tabindex="16" class="deviceType" data-bind="value: sselectedDeviceConfig, 
                                              optionsCaption : ovd.ui.admin.hart.selectDevice, 
                                              options: sdeviceConfigMap,
                                              optionsText: 'name',
                                              optionsValue: 'config_id', 
                                              event: { change: associateConfigWithValve}"><option value="">Select Device</option><option value="20">Dresser Masoneilan, SVI II AP / H7, initial, Linear</option><option value="21">Dresser Masoneilan, SVI II AP / H7, initial, Equal % (30)</option><option value="22">Dresser Masoneilan, SVI II AP / H7, initial, Quick Opening</option><option value="23">Dresser Masoneilan, SVI II AP / H7, initial, Linear</option></select>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using selectbyvalue or selectbyindex ?

Comment: @Neha kindly post your html code as we not able see your select tag text.

Comment: @Prany - I tried selectByValue also. But it didnt work

Comment: ok please paste the HTML here then as asked above@Neha

Comment: @Neha can you please post html rather snapshot.

Comment: updated the question with the html code

Comment: The Drop-down you are trying to access is in the middle tab (Device Configuration) of the 3 that are present.  Please check in case there are any frames or iframes involved; that would explain the not intractable error

Comment: No thats not the case for me. Also I am able to click on the tab easily.

Answer (score 1):

Your element is not visible at the time of Webdriver inteacting.Please wait for the element to be visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40); 
Select select=new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@class='deviceType']"))));
select.selectByIndex(1); //n=1,2...n
```

or 
select.selectByVisibleText(arg0);

Comment: your element is not visible so you have to wait for visible.Please try the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath( "//select[@class='deviceType']")); 
        dropdown.sendKeys(deviceOption);